# JavaScript append element by data.length

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem with append `<span>` element in my project. I want to show `<span>` element in real time. But I got multiple `<span>`

I have a view that looks like this:

```
<div class="view"> 
    <p>Hello World!.</p>
</div>
<textarea></textarea>
```

The condition that I want is when I input like `{{hello}}`, then it will count as `data.length = 1`, if I input like `{{hello}}{{my}}{{name}}`, then it will count as `data.length = 3`

Then, I am using `onkeyup` function to count the real time `data.length`

```
$('textarea').on('keyup', function(e) {
    var checkMustaches = $(this).match(/\{{\w+\}}/g);
    if(checkMustaches && checkMustaches.length > 0){
        for(let i = 0; i < checkMustaches.length; i++){
           $('.view p').append('<span>'+checkMustaches[i]+'</span>')
         }
    }

});
```

The problem is when I input something like this in my textarea `hello {{name}}{{id}}` . When I inspect it, It display like this

```
<div class="view"> 
    <p>hello 
      <span>{{name}}</span>
      <span>{{name}}</span>
      <span>{{name}}</span>
      <span>{{name}}</span>
      <span>{{name}}</span>
      <span>{{name}}</span>
      <span>{{name}}</span>
      <span>{{name}}</span>
      <span>{{id}}</span>
      <span>{{id}}</span>
    </p>
</div>
<textarea></textarea>
```

and If I delete the `{{id}}` it will add the `<span>{{name}}</span>` again

The things that I want is something is real time, like when I clear the mustache.. it will clear the span too

Comment: Do you delete the content of `.view`?

Comment: I think in you case will be very good to use library: vue.js (for dynamic generation of html content)

Comment: Why do you count **and** append at the same time?

Comment: Yap, but something that i want is when I clear one of all mustache in my textarea, it will also clear in my .view @MEE

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski I can't use library, because this is only dummy question, I only want to get the concept and then put into my real project

Comment: what should I do? do you have any idea for me? I am blank right now @Adelin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to clear your `p`'s content on each `event`

```
$('textarea').on('keyup', function(e) {
    $('.view p').html('')
    var checkMustaches = $(this).match(/\{{\w+\}}/g);
    if(checkMustaches && checkMustaches.length > 0){
        for(let i = 0; i < checkMustaches.length; i++){
           $('.view p').append('<span>'+checkMustaches[i]+'</span>')
         }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I've corrected some errors in your code and added the code to clear the `span`.

```js
$('textarea').on('keyup', function(e) {
  $('.view p').html("");
  var checkMustaches = $(this).val().match(/\{\{\w+\}\}/g);
  if(checkMustaches && checkMustaches.length > 0){
    for(let i = 0; i < checkMustaches.length; i++){
      $('.view p').append('<span>'+checkMustaches[i]+'</span>')
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="view"> 
    <p>Hello World!.</p>
</div>
<textarea></textarea>
```